# Slide com margens "Estouradas" com owl carousel 2

Tags: html5, css3, owl-carousel

Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer um slide nesse estilo da imagem abaixo usando `owl-carousel 2`
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Percebam que nas extremidades só e mostrado uma parte dos boxes.

Comment: Fiz isto acidentalmente há poucos dias, mas não faço ideia de como fiz. Adiciona seu código com css, js e html pra facilitar  o entendimento.

Comment: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/center.html e aqui https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/stagepadding.html